# Android GCM Registration with more information

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I implemented GCM to my app as described Getting Started page and used gcm.jar and gcm-server.jar helper libraries for easier implementation.

But I think I misunderstood something with GCM; beucase I couldn't achieve what i want.

I want that register devices with another key information not only registerId.
For example this is a weather application and user may want to get notifications about one city or more cities. To achieve this, server needs the city name or postal code to fetch weather information from other sources and push back to the registered devices if there is any change at releated cities.

I register device when user stated to get notifications about something particular (for example city).

However `GCMRegistrar.register` method only takes 2 arguments, one for context and one for senderID.

How can I send additional parameters to application server?

edit: I implemented GCMIntentService and onRegistered method. I can send additional information from here with directly calling server; but i lose additional information when onRegistered method called.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing stopping you from implementing your own code to send information to your app server. I've done that with my app. in the GCMIntentService class you created insert code to do so inside of your

```
protected void onRegistered(Context context,String regId)
```

method. You'll notice google's GCM library doesn't actually do any of the 3rd party app server registration as it did with C2DM. You can choose to use googles app engine if you wish.

Comment: you are right but i lost my key information when onRegistered method called. I am sorry i couldn't understand what you mean "to use google app engine if you wish"

Comment: You don't lose your key information. It's stored in your App's SharedPreferences. You can retrieve it from anywhere. And Google provides an App Engine for development. I've never used it but you could look into it. I know GCM interfaces with it.

Comment: SharedPreferences? I have never heard it before, but now I am checking . Thank you